# Can't find reason for computer shutdown on GPU intensive processes

Tags: shutdown, gpu, ubuntu-16.04

I am training a deep neural network on my GeForce 1080 GPU, and getting shutdowns without warning. I am monitoring gpu temperature but it does not rise above 88, and increasing the GPU fan does not help. Also lowering the power limit from 180W to 170W does not help.

If the GPU was overheating both of these changes should have some effect right? What else can I do to debug the cause of these shutdowns?

Comment: Please add info on the PSU used and the other power-hungry components.

Comment: Do you have the latest driver installed for the Ge Force?

Comment: @Moab I have driver version 384.130 and have not upgraded since it was a pain to get all drivers and versions to get to work on my system